# Replace the value of a variable when testing a function

Tags: node.js, testing, mocha.js, chai

I have a route that records user data and gives a unique identifier.

```
router.post('/', (req, res) => {
    const user_email = req.body.user_email;
    const username = req.body.username;
    const user_phone = req.body.user_phone;
    const service_sid = serviceSidVerification(user_phone);
    const entry_id = uuidv4();
    const user = new User(
        username,
        user_email,
        user_password,
        user_phone,
        entry_id,
        service_sid,
    );
    await db.query(user.setUser());
    return res.status(200).json({
        entry_id: entry_id,
    });
});
```

I want to write a test for this route. I need to replace the return value from the `serviceSidVerification()` function with my own. For example, `12345`. How can this be done with a test?

This is what my test looks like.

```
describe(`Users Test`, () => {
    describe('POST /api/users/', () => {
        it(`Should create user`, (done) => {
            let stub = sinon.createStubInstance(server);
            stub.getEvents.returns('12345')
            chai
                .request(server)
                .post('/api/users/')
                .send({ 'username': faker.internet.userName() })
                .send({ 'user_email': faker.internet.email() })
                .send({ 'user_password': faker.internet.password() })
                .send({ 'user_phone': faker.phone.phoneNumber() })
                .end((err, res) => {
                    expect(res).have.status(200);
                    expect(res.body).have.property('entry_id');
                    expect(res.body.entry_id).to.be.an('string');
                    done();
                });
            });
        });
    });
});

...

function ServiceSidVerification(phone) {
    const client = new twilio(config.smsVerify.accountSid, config.smsVerify.authToken);
    const service_sid = (await client.verify.services
        .create({
            friendlyName: config.smsVerify.title,
            codeLength: config.smsVerify.codeLength,
        })
    ).sid;
    const sid = (await client.verify.services(service_sid).verifications
        .create({
            to: phone,
            channel: 'sms'
        })
    ).sid;
    return { service_sid, sid };
}
```

How do I test my route?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the behavior of `serviceSidVerification()` you can use [sinon](https://sinonjs.org/releases/latest/stubs/). If you decide to go this way, you'll have to require `sinon` in the tests file + the module, where `serviceSidVerification` resides. Then, before executing the test you'll have to do something like this:

```
const stubServiceSidVerification = sinon.stub(yourModule, 'serviceSidVerification')
    .returns('yourValue');
```

*Please note that if you use `sinon`, `serviceSidVerification` should be exported as the property of an object and not as a standalone function because of this [issue](https://github.com/sinonjs/sinon/issues/562).*

Another option is to use [proxyquire](https://www.npmjs.com/package/proxyquire).

Comment: I get an error `Cannot stub non-existent own property serviceSidVerification`

Comment: Can you share the code where `serviceSidVerification` is defined and exported and the code where you try to stub it?

Comment: Added. The function is in the same file.

Comment: What `sinon` can do is stub(replace) the specified function when a test calls the API that uses that function. In your case it could change the behavior of `serviceSidVerification` when the test hits the endpoint. In order to do that, that function must be required and stubbed where the test is executed.
You've said that `serviceSidVerification` is defined in the 'same file' - what file do you mean?
Also, I can't see where it gets stubbed. I see `sinon.createStubInstance(server)` but I'm not sure that this is what is needed in this case.

Comment: I cannot figure out how to test this route. Is there an example or explanation?

Comment: You could use a tutorial like this one: https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-test-nodejs-apps-using-mocha-chai-and-sinonjs or try first to test something simpler just to get to know how things work.